Why am I not able to use Instant App on my Android device?
I have been trying to use the Instant App feature on my phone for 3 days now, but I haven't been able to. By Instant App feature, I mean the features shown in the video posted on this page. One of the features is being able to try the app/game with the "TRY NOW" button without installing it as shown in this screenshot,

What have I tried?
I have enabled Instant App for my account in Play Store by following this instruction. I have multiple Google accounts and I have turned it on for all of them.
I also tried it on multiple devices like Samsung Galaxy S, Android Pixel, Emulator, etc, all of which have the latest versions of Android.
Any help, feedback, and thoughts would be much appreciated.

What do you see, what error do you get

@RohitGupta, no error; just don't see "TRY NOW" button at all. That entire column/line shows just "INSTALL" button, unlike seen in the screenshot.

Most of the information here comes from these reddit posts:
Are instant apps dead?
What happened to Google Play Instant?
Short Answer: Instant Apps don't really exist anymore. There are no apps (that I can find) on the Play Store with the "Try now" feature as shown in your screenshot. Although, you can find some Instant Games on the Google Games app. Usually they don't have a full app that goes with them, though.
Long Answer:
Instant apps fell into two categories:

Instant Games
Instant Apps that opened from a link

For Instant Games, devs didn't want to put in the effort to maintain a separate Instant App version of their game that only a small portion of users would ever see. According to Google Play Instant documentation, developers had to greatly shrink their app size in order to make an Instant App, and if most users didn't ever use the Instant App, it didn't really make sense from a development perspective. There are still some Instant Games on the Google Games app, but most of them don't have a full application that goes with them because of the extra dev work that goes with it. Some of these Instant Games on the Google Games app are made by Google as well.
Instant Apps (that opened from a link) on the other hand, didn't really ever have a use. The idea was that links could be opened in small apps for increased functionality. However, if there was a link, a webpage usually worked just fine. Instant Apps from a link tried to fix a problem that didn't exist.
As a result, Instant Apps faded away over time. I can't find any examples of Instant Games on the play store, or any links that open in instant apps. They aren't officially depreciated, and as far as I can tell, developers could still make an Instant App if they wanted to, there just isn't a need to make one.

Thanks much for summarizing it!

@Dhunju_likes_to_Learn No problem, if you think my answer answered your question sufficiently, you can press the green check below the down arrow to mark it as accepted.
